# Does the direct sum decomposition of a p-group tell you the number of Prüfer subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, p-groups

My understanding is that every countable Abelian $p$-group can be written as a direct sum of at most countably many finite cyclic groups and at most countably many copies of the [Prüfer $p$-group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group).

Suppose that when such a direct-sum decomposition is written for a particular countable Abelian $p$-group $G$, there are $N$ copies of the Prüfer $p$-group in the decomposition, where $N$ can be $0$, finite, or infinite.  Then my question is, does that mean that there are exactly $N$ subgroups of $G$ that are isomorphic to the Prüfer $p$-group?  Or can there be more than $N$ such subgroups?

Comment: Try with $N=0,1,2$.

Comment: @reuns I’d love to “try” those numbers, but I have no idea how.  Do you know if the statement is true for those three numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(in additives notations)

With $N=0$ then $$G=\prod_{n\ge 1}' \Bbb{Z}/p^{k_n} \Bbb{Z}$$ where $\prod'$ means we consider the 'sequences' $x_n\in  \Bbb{Z}/p^{k_n} \Bbb{Z}$ with only finitely many terms $\ne 0$.

For $x,y\in G$, $x = p^m y$ implies that $x_n=0$ whenever $m\ge k_n$.

Thus there is no non-zero element $x\in G$ such that $\forall m, \exists y\in G,x=p^m y$ ie. there is no copy of $\Bbb{Z}[p^{-1}]/\Bbb{Z}$ in $G$.

With $N=1$ we are looking at $G\times \Bbb{Z}[p^{-1}]/\Bbb{Z}$ and it works more or less the same way.

With $N=2$ we are looking at $G\times \Bbb{Z}[p^{-1}]/\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z}[p^{-1}]/\Bbb{Z}$ and something different happens.

Comment: What is the thing different that happens at $N=2$?  How many subgroups of it are isomorphic to the Prufer p-group?

Comment: How many do you see ?

Comment: I have no idea how I’d go about “seeing” it.  I know there’s at least two, but it’s not clear to me whether there’s more than two or not.

Comment: Try constructing a 3rd one.

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m really not sure how to do that.  In any case, are there just three subgroups isomorphic to the Prufer p-group or even more?  Is there a general formula for the number of subgroups isomorphic to the Prufer p-group if there are N copies of the Prufer p-groups in the direct sum?

Comment: Is $\{ (s,s), s\in \Bbb{Z}[p^{-1}]/\Bbb{Z}\}$ a group ?

Comment: OK yeah, I see, that is another group isomorphic to the Prufer p-group (when combined with a string from G in the beginning).  So is that the only one or are there even more?  Are there infinitely many subgroups isomorphic to the Prufer p-group.

Comment: Why don't you try and see ?

Comment: Maybe changing the string from G?  So like one group may be the set of all (0,s,s), another group may be the set of all (-1,s,s), (0,s,s), (1,s,s), another group may be the set of all (-2,s,s), (-1,s,s), (0,s,s), (1,s,s) (2,s,s), etc.?  This isn’t homework or anything, by the way.  I’m a PhD student studying mathematical logic, and in the course of my research something related to Abelian p-groups came up.  That’s why I’m not good at figuring these things out, I don’t have much background in algebra.

Comment: Do you really think that it will be a group ?

Comment: I’m not really sure, I was just trying something.

Comment: Anyway, can you please just tell me the answer as to how many subgroups there are?  And the formula for how many subgroups there are in the general case when you have have N Prufer groups in the direct sum?

Comment: For any integer $n$, $\{ (s,sn),s\in Z[p^{-1}]/Z\}$ is a copy. In fact it stays true for any $p$-adic integer $n$, ie. a sequence of integers that converges $\bmod$ every $p^k$.   The (uncountably many) copies are then $\{ (s,sn),s\in Z[p^{-1}]/Z\},n\in Z_p$ and $\{ (ns,s),s\in Z[p^{-1}]/Z\},n\in pZ_p$.

Comment: OK thanks.  Now let me ask you this.  Suppose that $G$ is bounded, in the sense that there is some $k$ such that there are no finite cyclic groups that go into the direct product that are of order greater than $p^k$.  Then how many elements are there of order $p^{k+1}$ in the case of $N=2$?